# Error message when using HtmlHelper with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, html-helper

Brand-new CakePHP user; just got the install up and running a few hours ago (or so I thought.) I've been running through the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/326/The-Cake-Blog-Tutorial) and everything was going swimmingly, until I hit the Adding Posts section. I thought maybe I had made a typo somewhere, so I copied and pasted the code directly out of the tutorial, and I'm still getting these errors when I try to go to localhost/cakeBlogTest/posts/add. Can anyone help me out? I installed the most recent stable version of CakePHP.

> Warning (512): Method HtmlHelper::input does not exist [CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 143]
>
> Warning (512): Method HtmlHelper::tagErrorMsg does not exist [CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 143]
>
> Warning (512): Method HtmlHelper::textarea does not exist [CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 143]
>
> Warning (512): Method HtmlHelper::submit does not exist [CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 143]

EDITED TO ADD:

I was able to use $html->link in another section of the tutorial, so it does seem to be finding the helpers file. I just looked at the helper file, and input, textarea, and submit do exist, but tagErrorMsg does not. Is it possible the tutorial is out-of-date and using bits that no longer exist in the current version of CakePHP? And if so, what do I use in place of tagErrorMsg?

MORE ADDITIONS:

Code copy/pasted directly from tutorial:

```
<h1>Add Post</h1>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $html->url('/posts/add')?>">
    <p>
        Title:
        <?php echo $html->input('Post/title', array('size' => '40'))?>
        <?php echo $html->tagErrorMsg('Post/title', 'Title is required.') ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        Body:
        <?php echo $html->textarea('Post/body', array('rows'=>'10')) ?>
        <?php echo $html->tagErrorMsg('Post/body', 'Body is required.') ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo $html->submit('Save') ?>
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input`, `textarea`, `submit` are **not** functions of `HtmlHelper`  they belong to `FormHelper`

In your views you should use `$this->Form->input('test')` instead of `$this->Html->input('test')`

[This tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/326/The-Cake-Blog-Tutorial) belongs to cakephp v1.1 (obviously out-of-date)

Learn cakePHP's [latest tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog) v1.3

Comment: That's not what the tutorial says. I'm adding the code, pasted directly from the tutorial, in the OP. That's why I asked if the tutorial was out-of-date and using things that don't exist anymore.

Comment: Thank you! I was given the URL for the tutorial by someone else; didn't realize the "Collections" listed at the top were the same thing for newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Now the tagErrorMsg function is changed to tagIsInvalid and it is now in "FormHelper" class but before it was in HtmlHelper class.So now onwards we should to use it like->
$this->Form->tagIsInvalid() or $form->tagIsInvalid() 
AND NOT LIKE $this->Html->tagIsInvalid()